# Should I provide fingering for a piano music sheet?

Tags: piano, notation, sheet-music, fingering

I am typesetting a piano piece and am wondering if I should provide fingering instructions. First I thought that it could be helpful, but I'm not sure if this is considered normal by professional pianists.

Is it normal to provide fingering instructions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In editions of classic literature, sometimes fingering is provided by the composer, and sometimes it is added by an editor. A typical edition of a late Beethoven sonata will have Beethoven's fingerings in Italic type and the editor's fingering in normal type (or the other way around). These fingerings can be very helpful for a student learning a difficult piece, for instance by Brahms or Liszt.

On the other hand, Debussy published his etudes without fingerings, commenting in a preface that not all fingerings suit all hands, and as part of the challenge of the etudes, students should find their own fingerings. (See a discussion here: https://www.henle.de/blog/en/2012/05/14/debussy-to-finger-or-not-to-finger%E2%80%A6-why-we-are-adding-fingering-in-the-%E2%80%9Cetudes%E2%80%9D/)

My opinion: if the piece is not particularly difficult it probably does not need fingering. But if there is a part that is difficult to play or depends on a trick fingering, then include the fingering.

As an example, a scale passage usually can use the standard fingering we all learned when practicing our scales. But sometimes you need to end on a particular finger because of what comes next, and to do that you have to start on a particular finger, or use 2-3-4-1-2-3 where you might use 2-3-1-2-3-4. Indicating the fingering can be helpful and will be appreciated.

Fingerings are especially helpful if the piece is likely to be sight-read or learned quickly for a performance, as for instance music for church services, or vocal scores for rehearsing musical shows.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! And the link, it was quite interesting to read. It seems from the link, actually, that Debussy just wanted to avoid providing fingering instructions.